# Can a copy of the blockchain hold private information?

Tags: monerod, blockchain, privacy

I want to run a daemon on another machine, and I was thinking of copying the blockchain I already have (copying the entire `.bitmonero` folder). I'm curious whether any private information may be leaked by doing that, such as information about the machine that this blockchain was synced on (IP, name, OS...) or information about wallets that used this copy of the blockchain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blockchain itself will not (beyond its endianness), but some other files might: the logs, in particular, might contain paths specific to your computer (not saying they definitely will). The p2pstate.bin file will contain your node's peer id (though this is now reset on every restart), and may also leak information on the version of boost it was built with. That's all I can think of right now. No wallet information will be there (unless of course you chose to store your wallet there).

Comment: So, should copying only the `lmdb` folder be safe?

Comment: That should be fine. There's a lock file there, in addition to the db, but I don't think it will leak anything beyond possibly endianness and bit depth (I don't know whether it does or not, that's just abundance of caution). But then the lock file is useless to the other machine, so might as well copy just data.mdb in the first place.